# Can't convert JSON from WebApi to Json Object in Android

Tags: c#, android, json, asp.net-web-api

i'm currently developing and android app that collects data from ASP.NET WebApi Service. The service works but i can't  get the JSON object in android,DO i have to convert to JSON array or to JSON object, i have tried alot of answers out there but no success. Here is my server side code  snippet:

```
 // GET api/uconnectservice
        public String Get()
        {

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(

                sampledata.GetAllDummy()
            );
            return json;

            //return sampledata.GetAll();
        }
```

which gives :

```
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
    [{"AccountType":"15516321","CustomerName":"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"1100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"15/12/2016 22:35:03","ValueDate":"15/12/2016 22:35:03"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"16/12/2016 22:35:03","ValueDate":"16/12/2016 22:35:03"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"17/12/2016 22:35:03","ValueDate":"17/12/2016 22:35:03"}......MORE JSON.........{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"20/12/2016 22:35:03","ValueDate":"20/12/2016 22:35:03"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"21/12/2016 22:35:03","ValueDate":"21/12/2016 22:35:03"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"22/12/2016 22:35:03","ValueDate":"22/12/2016 22:35:03"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"23/12/2016 22:35:03","ValueDate":"23/12/2016 22:35:03"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"24/12/2016 22:35:03","ValueDate":"24/12/2016 22:35:03"}]}]
</string>
```

etc which is fine

On the android side where i have to consume this service here is my code:

```
String URL = "http://192.168.1.101/UnicsApplication/api/uconnectservice";

    JSONObject jsonObject;
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void run() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL).build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {

                    if (!response.isSuccessful())

                        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();

                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {

                        Log.d("Results", responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));

                    }
                    //Log.d("Results", responseBody.string());

                    try {
                        //get JSON objetc first 

                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody.string());

                        Log.d("JsonObject", jsonObject.toString());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

The e.printstackTrance method is called.Error message i keep getting from Logcat is as follows:

```
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192): org.json.JSONException: Value {"operations":[{"AccountType":"15516321","CustomerName":"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS","Currentbalance":"1100,000.00","AllTransactions":[{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"16/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"16/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"17/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"17/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"18/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"18/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"19/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"19/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"20/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"20/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"21/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"21/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"22/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"22/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"23/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"23/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"24/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"24/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"50010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"25/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"25/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"16/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"16/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"17/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"17/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"18/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"18/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":109,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15004","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"19/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"19/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":111,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15005","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"20/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"20/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":113,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15006","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"21/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"21/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":115,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15007","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"22/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"22/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":117,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15008","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"23/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"23/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":119,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"15009","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"24/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"24/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":121,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I'am putting in money right now","Debit":"150010","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"25/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"25/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":103,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5001","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"16/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"16/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":105,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5002","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"17/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"17/12/2016 01:59:45"},{"ID":107,"DescriptionoOfTransaction":"I need money right now","Debit":"5003","Credit":"0","TransactionDate":"18/12/2016 01:59:45","ValueDate":"18/12/20
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at com.nickSoft.Connections.OkHttpHandlerIncoming$1.onResponse(OkHttpHandlerIncoming.java:67)
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:126)
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-15 01:59:44.280: W/System.err(26192):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Is this a JSON string? what can i do to get JSON object which will be later converted to a collection?.Please any guidance or help will greatly appreciated. Thnx.

Comment: try adding an accept header `accept:application/json` to your request.  This should prompt the server to return JSON instead of an XML string.  Edit: you would also not need to serialize your object on the server side or return string.  Just return whatever object it is, it looks like maybe Account or List<Account>, and WebApi will take care of serialization for you

Comment: ok @Borophyll trying that now,btw how can i impement do what u just suggested? i'm a little confused.

Comment: it would help if you post the code where you submit the request to your api (android side) so I can see what you have already tried

Comment: Ok @Borophyll i just included that code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">`

is not valid JSON, looks like you got first some xml that contains json. My suggestion is to strip it down correctly on the server side. If that is not possible remove the string tags from the response before you start parsing

Comment: thnks @QVDev i added this piece of code:            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
    .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html")); in the web config(server) and got only JSON howwever my logcat show this error.Pls see question edit.....

Comment: Try validation your response in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ making sure you return a valid JSON on the server.